# Is there a way to update the Realm Browser when data is changed besides downloading the container from device each time?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-browser

Currently, each time I run the app and change data, in order to see it in the Realm Browser, I follow the following steps:

1) Window -> Devices

2) Device -> Installed App -> MyApp -> Download Container

3) Show Package Contents -> AppData -> Documents -> Open .realm file

This is time-consuming and would be helpful if we could "refresh" Realm Browser?

Comment: Realm Browser doesn't support that functionality, but it is developed publicly and you may file a ticket requesting that feature at its GitHub page: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx

Comment: This doesn't address the Realm refresh issue but to get to the `.realm` file quickly I use [SimSim](https://github.com/dsmelov/simsim) which places an icon in the menu bar that sends you directly to the directory for any app in the simulator.